# How to "rebuild" git repo?

Tags: git

I have something strange going on with some of my repos .. Xcode seems to think i have uncommitted changes whereas `git status` affirms all is well.

What would be the cleanest way to:

1. Delete existing repo
2. Add all project files to new repo

I suppose i can copy all the files into new directory and

```
1. git init .
2. git add . 
3. git commit -a -m "initial commit"
```

But before I do this, i'd like a second opinion.

Comment: Why you think Xcode's thought is wrong? What git said?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before you go throwing the baby out with the bathwater, maybe you should try this:

```
git clone /path/to/your/original/repo
```

See what Xcode thinks of the newly cloned repo.